# Redshift ROLLBACK for COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to `ROLLBACK` a `COPY` operation in Redshift? What could be the best approach to remove only those rows inserted only as part of the `COPY` operation in a table that has data appended?

Comment: It's possible if you disable autocommit before running `copy` - but a `rollback` will roll back **everything**. `copy` is done in a single transaction

Comment: i think the difficult is autocommit, but you can copy the data to new table and then use minus to remove the old data (if you dont have duplicated rows it's will be fine)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, could you show how that is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `copy` can be rolled back *only* within a transaction. If you committed a `copy`, then it can't be rolled back.

As to your 2nd question, this is something that your application layer needs to manage. Examples:

- Preprocess your file to add an additional marker column, such as `copy-id`, in your data. So, when you need to remove data loaded by a `copy`, you delete all rows corresponding to the `copy-id`.
- If data is loaded once every day, you can create [time-series tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-time-series-tables.html). So, rolling back a `copy` that ran on a particular day involves truncating the corresponding table. You can also think of creating one table per week, depending on your use case.